# Нужно чтобы по клику на ссылку переход не осуществлялся, но действие выполнялось

Tags: jquery, ссылки, меню

Есть такая проблема что при адапте нужно чтобы клик по ссылкам не осуществлял переход, но чтобы действие (открытие подменю) все-таки выполнялось.
Меню многоуровневое, и на десктопной версии ссылки (заголовки категорий) ведут на страницу товаров это категории, но при адапте этого происходить не должно.
Вот такой вот код (это только фрагмент)

```
if($(window).width() < 1130){
   $('#shops-category-open-menu').removeClass('shops-hover');
   $('#shops-category-open-btn').click( function(e){
     $('#shops-category-open-btn').toggleClass('open-catalog');
     $('#shops-category-open-menu').slideToggle();
     return false
  })};
```

Когда забираю return false происходит переход и меню закрывается.

Comment: Вернее не так. когда есть return false то все правильно работает, действие исполняется, переход нет, но дочерние ссылки тоже не происходит переход, а должен.

Comment: "дочерние ссылки" - та-а-ак, это что значит?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `e.preventDefault();`:

```js
if($(window).width() < 1130){
       $('#shops-category-open-menu').removeClass('shops-hover');
       $('#shops-category-open-btn').click( function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log('Clicked');
         $('#shops-category-open-btn').toggleClass('open-catalog');
         $('#shops-category-open-menu').slideToggle();
      })};
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<a href="#" id="shops-category-open-btn">Click to me</a>
```

В консоли выводится "Clicked", соответственно последующий код тоже выполняется, переход по ссылке (в данном случае по #) не происходит.

Comment: пробовал не выполняется ничего, ни переход, ни действие, и меню закрывается

Comment: @Влад пример обновил, в консоли выводится "Clicked", соответственно последующий код тоже выполняется, переход по ссылке (в данном случае по #) не происходит.